# wp_list_pages sort order is different for different languages

Tags: menus, pages, wp-list-pages, sort

I'm using the following code

```
wp_list_pages(array('exclude' => '','title_li' => '','sort_column' => 'menu_order'))
```

If I switch the language the sorting is different. One of the main menu points is listed at the end of the page when switching to my second language. Why does this happen? The pages have a sorting of zero when editing a page ...

Comment: Maybe because the order is alphabetically ?

Comment: @user983248: Definitely not. Perhaps it has to do with WPML and the synchronizing ..

Comment: @testing, I think you should state in your question that you're using WPML. Being that the case, maybe you should ask in their support forums. And final note: if you have a sorting of "zero", what happens if you actually give them sorting numbers?